# Displaying dropdown submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm making a mobile dropdown menu, and within this menu there are sub menus that will open (like a drop down menu) and push the list down. I got most of this done but the sub menu doesn't display properly. Instead of being under an entity of the list, it appears next to it. (It pushes the rest of the list down, which is a plus. I found if I set the sub menu position to absolute it would appear properly but it would not push the rest of the list down)

Also, if I were to change the "list-style-type" to none (I don't want the bullet points), the entire menu breaks...Not sure why.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dropdownmobile" class="mobile-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/test">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="mobhasdrop"><a>Menu 2 - Click Me</a><img src="/img/logo.png"/>
      <ul class="mobdropdown">
        <li><a href="">Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dropdown 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dropdown 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li class="mobhasdrop"><a href="">Menu 5 - This one too</a><img src="/img/logo.png"/>
      <ul class="mobdropdown">
        <li><a href="">Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dropdown 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dropdown 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mobile-content {
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.mobile-content ul {
    margin-top: 32px;
}

.mobile-content ul li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.mobile-content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.mobile-content img {
    float: right;
}

.mobile-content li.mobhasdrop {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

.mobdropdown {
    background-color: #f00;
    display: none;
}
.mobdropdown li{
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("li.mobhasdrop").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.mobdropdown').slideToggle();
})
```

Here's a jsfiddle - JQuery might not be enabled by default (oops)

https://jsfiddle.net/xschoolboyx/ddL439zm/

Comment: try to take a look to the updated fiddle. Let me know if it will help you. https://jsfiddle.net/ddL439zm/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `float: left` on `.mobile-content a`, which I believe fixed most of your issues, including being able to use `list-style: none`. I also moved the two `<img>` elements above their corresponding links so that `float: right` works properly on them (as elements with that property should be above the associated left-aligned elements).

```js
    $("li.mobhasdrop").click(function() {
      $(this).find('.mobdropdown').slideToggle();
    })
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.mobile-content {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-content ul {
  margin-top: 32px;
}
.mobile-content ul li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.mobile-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*float: left;*/
}
.mobile-content img {
  float: right;
}
.mobile-content li.mobhasdrop {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobdropdown {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: none;
}
.mobdropdown li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdownmobile" class="mobile-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/test">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobhasdrop">
      <img src="/img/logo.png" />
      <a>Menu 2 - Click Me</a>
      <ul class="mobdropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobhasdrop">
      <img src="/img/logo.png" />
      <a href="#">Menu 5 - This one too</a>
      <ul class="mobdropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, works almost perfectly. The only thing that still doesn't really make sense is the space that's left when you open the menu. (Bit of black space between menu 2 and dropdown 1. I thought it was margin-top inherited from another ul but it doesnt look like it ) Either way, not really a big deal

Comment: @xschoolboyx You haven't removed the browser default `margin` and `padding` styles that are applied to `ul` elements automatically. Add `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` to the `ul {}` rule I added on top of your CSS so you have full control.